# when you enter an input field, throws an error although the whole model is correct. Python django

Tags: python, django

the form does not pass validation and throws an error, although the correct data is entered, what is the problem?

I enter in the input field `+79211234569` and gives an error in html **Select the correct option. Your option is not among the valid values.**

form data: `<'form': <RelatedAddForm bound=True, valid=False, fields=(name;phone)>`

**forms**

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = 'include/_forms_clients_datalist.html'

    def format_value(self, value):
        # Copied from forms.Input - makes sure value is rendered properly
        if value == '' or value is None:
            print('ListTextWidget None')
            return ''
        if self.is_localized:
            print('ListTextWidget local')
            return formats.localize_input(value)
        return str(value)

class ChoiceTxtField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    widget=ListTextWidget()

class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = ChoiceTxtField(queryset=Clients.objects.order_by('-phone'))

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ['name', 'phone']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }
```

**models**

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, verbose_name='Имя')
    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$', message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 15 digits allowed.")
    phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], unique=True, max_length=17, verbose_name='Телефон')  

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('view_clients', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
```

**UPD:**

request_post `<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['m9mKTv4kLWSFmW6Jj39OUAZ0zINBoFjvphjYADWvY97lk1oKAB3LAHhxOpmXnKbo'], 'cli ents-name': ['test'], 'clients-phone': ['+79121234566']}>` passes the `name` variable and the `phone` variable in the correct format

Most likely the problem is that the check of the phone field is related to the `ChoiceTxtField`?

Comment: When you enter the in the input field the option `+79211234569 ` you try to get the option no. 79211234569 if I am not mistaken. And there's clearly not that much option in your select inside your html.

Comment: i updated the post [UPD].  data is passed but not processed in class RelatedAddForm (forms.ModelForm). I think the problem is in the ChoiceTxtField, but I cannot figure out how to solve

Answer (score 0):

ModelChoiceField assumes selection of a previously saved model only (specified in the queryset parameter). There is no need to inherit ModelChoiceField, changes are made at the widget level. Therefore, you need to replace it with CharField.

```
class ListTextWidget(forms.Select):
    template_name = 'include/_forms_clients_datalist.html'

class PhoneInputField(forms.CharField):
    widget=ListTextWidget()

class RelatedAddForm(forms.ModelForm):
    phone = PhoneInputField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone'].choices = Clients.objects.order_by('-phone').values_list('phone')

    class Meta:
        model = Clients
        fields = ['name', 'phone']
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'autocomplete': 'off'}),
        }
```